# Use a script to disable constraint in a table - sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a bunch of tables and a bunch of constraint along with it that prevent me from importing data from excel. I know that I have to disable the constraint using alter table "MyTableName" nocheck constraint "MyConstraints" and enable them back when the import is done.

Because there are quite a few tables with quite a few constraints, I have attempted to update everything from a script.

I had all the names of the table I wanted to disable into another table called MyTableList where the only column in there is the name of all the tables I want to disable.

I then use the following script to hopefully disable the constraint but I keep getting syntax error. (Without the alter table command, my script run fine).

How do I go around that and make the script run (manual enable and disable works but it is too time consuming)
The following is my script:

```
declare @TableInQuestion nvarchar(150)
declare @ConstraintInQuestion nvarchar(150)
declare MyConstraintToDisable cursor
    local static read_only forward_only
for
    SELECT        OBJECT_NAME(sys.objects.object_id) AS ConstraintName, 
                  OBJECT_NAME(sys.objects.parent_object_id) AS TableName
    FROM          sys.objects INNER JOIN
                  MyTableList 
    ON            OBJECT_NAME(sys.objects.parent_object_id) = MyTableList.Description
    WHERE         (sys.objects.type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT') 

open MyConstraintToDisable
fetch next from MyConstraintToDisable
into @ConstraintInQuestion, @TableInQuestion
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
   print @ConstraintInQuestion+', '+ @TableInQuestion 
   alter table @TableInQuestion nocheck constraint @ConstraintInQuestion
   print 'Done'
   fetch next from MyConstraintToDisable
   into @ConstraintInQuestion, @TableInQuestion
end
close MyConstraintToDisable
deallocate MyConstraintToDisable
```

It kept saying that the syntax alter table is not correct. Please help. I am a rookie in sql programming.

Comment: I would recommend using the more **focused** catalog views like `sys.tables` and `sys.default_constraints` etc. Also: when you do this, you must use **dynamic SQL**, e.g. you must construct the SQL statements as a `NVARCHAR` string, and then use `EXEC(@Stmt)` or `EXEC sp_executesql @stmt` to execute that statement

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're getting please

Comment: @PaulHunt: The syntax is cryptic and ambiguous. I am rookie in SQL programming and can not decipher what is actually incorrect.                 "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near '@TableInQuestion'."

Comment: If that proves hard to develop or maintain, you might also want to consider bulk loading with no constraints.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186247%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the value of a variable in a SQL statement you need to build a string and then execute that string. So I would change the line you currently have

> alter table @TableInQuestion nocheck constraint @ConstraintInQuestion

to something like this (untested)

> declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'alter table [' + @TableInQuestion + '] nocheck constraint [' + @ConstraintInQuestion + ']'
>
> exec(@sql)